# Subset a data frame for date and keep all later dates in data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, subset

I have the following `data.table`

```
DT <- data.table(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 date1=c("2013-11-22","2013-11-22","2013-11-22","2015-12-22","2015-12-22","2010-12-22","2010-12-22"),
                 variable=c(20.5,22.1,21.9,30.3,30.5,28.7,27.9))
```

I only want to keep the rows with the later dates to finally have this data frame

```
id      date1 variable
1:  1 2013-11-22     20.5
2:  1 2013-11-22     22.1
3:  1 2013-11-22     21.9
4:  2 2015-12-22     30.3
5:  2 2015-12-22     30.5
```

I am using data.table and tried something like this

```
setDT(DT)[,.SD[which.max(date1)],by='id']
```

But it only gives me the output for one row per `id`. I want to keep the rows with all the later dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `.I`

```
DT[DT[, .I[date1 == max(date1)], id]$V1]
#  id      date1 variable
#1:  1 2013-11-22     20.5
#2:  1 2013-11-22     22.1
#3:  1 2013-11-22     21.9
#4:  2 2015-12-22     30.3
#5:  2 2015-12-22     30.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
DT[, .SD[date1 == max(date1)], by = 'id']
```

Output:

```
   id      date1 variable
1:  1 2013-11-22     20.5
2:  1 2013-11-22     22.1
3:  1 2013-11-22     21.9
4:  2 2015-12-22     30.3
5:  2 2015-12-22     30.5
```